# MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor neuronFilter deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, conv-neural-network, metal-performance-shaders

In iOS 11.0 the neuronFilter was deprecated from some ConvolutionDespriptors.

I am still using this, but Xcode already complains about deprecation and this is due to the last argument:

```
  let desc = MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor(kernelWidth: kernel.0,
                                     kernelHeight: kernel.1,
                                     inputFeatureChannels: inChannels,
                                     outputFeatureChannels: outChannels,
                                     neuronFilter: activation)
```

Unfortunately the current Apple docs say nothing about how to solve the issue. The "neuronFilter" arguments needs to be removed from the call, but how do I employ it then ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"You must implement now the convolution family"** Anyhow neuronType, neuronParameterA and neuronParameterB...

The process has changed but not that much, I think you would do it without too much trouble.

And yes, neuronFilter is fully deprecated.

[image]

This is the new way to go:

**Declaration**

```
class MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor : NSObject
```

**Overview**

You use an **MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor** object to describe the properties of an MPSCNNConvolution kernel such as its size, pixel format and CPU cache mode.

Don't use a **MPSCNNNeuron** (neuronFilter) use a **MPSCNNKernel** instead.

You have a nice day!

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. All the "neuron"-related functions are deprecated (as you showed above). What does "You must implement now the convolution family" mean? Could you please give an example showing a function call! Thanks

Comment: I did expand my answer

Comment: Do I understand correctly that instead of specifying a neuronFilter now whole additional layer is required ? MPSCNNKernel is a just base class. How do I set it up to represent a simple ReLu ? Sorry for not getting it...

Answer (score 0):

from what I could see from the class deprecation message:

> This method is deprecated. Please use neuronType, neuronParameterA and neuronParameterB properites to fuse neuron with convolution.

Comment: MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor.neuronParameterA() etc. seem to be deprecated too ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling here desperately (like I did, but the guidance above is, well mysterious), the way to set neuron filter in non-deprecated (iOS11+) way is:

```
MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor *d = [MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor cnnConvolutionDescriptorWithKernelWidth:w kernelHeight:h inputFeatureChannels:i outputFeatureChannels:o];
[d setFusedNeuronDescriptor:[MPSNNNeuronDescriptor cnnNeuronDescriptorWithType:MPSCNNNeuronTypeReLU a:0]];
```

It is "documented" in [Swift version](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpscnnconvolutiondescriptor) of `MPSNNNeuronDescriptor` but not on Objective-C. Go figure.